# How can I link my Social Security Number to my online account in Bank of America?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, bank-account, social-security, bank-of-america

It is about a year I am in the U.S. and have an account at Bank of America. I also have a travel reward credit card, but when I wanted to get my credit report from Credit Karma, I was told they could not find my information, or there was a mistake in my information, but I am sure I did not make any mistake.

The only thing I am concerned about is that I have not linked my Social Security Number to my bank account. Honestly, I do not know how to link my SSN to my bank account! I searched the internet, but I could not find any useful hint.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, Bank of America, who you have a credit card with, is not reporting anything to your social security number's credit report, and you would like them to.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I am trying to make the account in Credit Karma, but in the second step of making the account, I got the following error.

Comment: Your personal information doesn't match with credit bureau records. Please review your information for any possible errors. For security reasons, you'll also need to reenter your Social Security Number before continuing. Not sure what's wrong? You can find some tips on the right side of this page.

Comment: But I am pretty sure, my info is the exact same as my bank account information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that you have a Social Security Number, if you want Bank of America to start reporting to your credit report so that you can establish a credit history, you'll need to contact Bank of America and ask them to attach your Social Security Number to your account.  It might be easiest to do this in person: bring your Social Security card into a Bank of America branch and see if they can help you.

Some sources online for more reading:

- UScreditcardguide.com: [Credit Cards You Can Get Without SSN](http://www.uscreditcardguide.com/credit-cards-you-can-get-without-ssn/) (Read "Conclusions" section at the end.)
- Quora.com: [Should I link my Social Security Number to my Bank Account?](https://www.quora.com/Should-I-link-my-Social-Security-Number-to-my-bank-account/answer/Eddie-Tang-11)
- Dreamact.info forum: [SSN and bank accounts - just more BS...](http://dreamact.info/forum/archive/index.php?t-33165.html)